# Angular - .publishLast is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to avoid to create multiple requests when I use `async` pipe.
I have the following request to get an user from api

```js
getUser() {
    this._user = this.http.get<User>(environment.baseAPIUrl + 'user')
      .pipe(
        tap((user: User) => {
          // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
          console.log(user);

          this.setIsVerified(user.verified);
          this.userReady = true;
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error.statusText);
            if (error.status === 403) {
              this.logout();
            }

            return throwError(error.error);
          }
        ))
      .publishLast()
      .refCount();;
  }
```

but when I try to run the app I have the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(...).pipe(...).publishLast is not a function
```

I tried to add
`import {catchError, tap, publishLast} from 'rxjs/operators';`
but the problem persists.

I use 
Angular 6 and 
`"rxjs": "^6.1.0"`

Comment: what you mean, sorry?

Comment: which version of rxjs?

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.1.0"

Comment: Operators go inside `pipe()`, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of RxJS v6.x, you need to put `publishLast()` as a parameter (argument) of `pipe`, something like following:

```
 getUser() {
      this._user = this.http.get<User>(environment.baseAPIUrl + 'user')
        .pipe(
          tap((user: User) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            console.log(user);

            this.setIsVerified(user.verified);
            this.userReady = true;
          }),
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              console.log(error.statusText);
              if (error.status === 403) {
                this.logout();
              }

              return throwError(error.error);
            }
          ),
          publishLast()
        )

        .refCount();;
    }
```

You should not chain `publishLast()` as you have done in RxJS v5.0.

Comment: yes it works, thanks. But I have to add also `refCount()` as parameter of `pipe`, is it normal?

Comment: Yes, refCount() automatically subscribe and unsubscribe when subscribers come and go. If you want to avoid refCount(), you may use shareReplay(1) instead of publishLast().

Comment: Please update your reply, `refCount();;` should be `.pipe(refCount());`